# State variable is not getting updated using react hook

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-hooks, use-state

I am learning ReactJS and trying to update the parent props with the updated state of ingredients from the child component. The setUserIngredients is called and updated ingredients are being passed to parent.

Code :

```
const [userIngredients, setUserIngredients] = useState([]);

const removeIngredientHandler = id => {
    setLoading(true);
    fetch(`https://***************.com/ingredients/${id}.json`,{
      method:'DELETE'
    }).then(response=>{
      setLoading(false);
      setUserIngredients(prevIngredients => 
        prevIngredients.filter(ingredient =>{
          return (ingredient.id !== id)
           //return  ingredient;
        })
      );
      **props.ingredients(userIngredients);**
      //userIngredients is still having old value 
      //need to check on this
    }).catch(error => {
      setError(error.message);
    })
  };
```

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks  Alex. It answers my question partially. How to resolve this as I am not using class component?

Comment: The class based `setState` and the `setWhateverState` from a useState hook are the same in this way. They trigger a render, and that render will have the updated value. Simple as that.

Comment: Yes, I understand they trigger a render but as they are asynchronous in nature, my parent callback is executed before the setState method. As per my understanding, they are triggering the render after the parent call which is why the parent is not having the latest ingredients.

Comment: Sorry I closed this one, I see your issue now. I'll once I can get the question back open.

Comment: Thanks, Alex. Please open the issue again and don't mark it as duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `userIngredients` is a variable that is created when the component renders, set to a version fo the state when that component renders. And when you start an asynchronous operation (like a fetch) the callback you pass to that operation will be bound the values from when that callback was created.

The fix here is pretty simple. In the spot where you calculate your new ingredients, simply execute whatever callback you need before returning the value to be stored in the state.

Something like:

```
fetch(`https://***************.com/ingredients/${id}.json`, {
  method: 'DELETE',
}).then(response => {
  setLoading(false)
  setUserIngredients(prevIngredients => {
    // Figure out the new ingredients
    const newIngredients = prevIngredients.filter(ingredient => ingredient.id !== id)

    // Call your callback with the new ingredients
    props.ingredients(newIngredients)

    // Return the new ingredients to be stored in your state
    return newIngredients
  })
})
```